# Why does filter: alpha(opacity=100) break my printouts? (IE7 & IE8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a webpage which lists data in a tabular format.

The markup looks basically like this:

```
<div style="filter: alpha(opacity=100)">
...Lots of other markup
<table>
    ..data from backend
</table>
</div>
```

However, when I print this page, using IE8 or IE7 the resulting print is very strange, several rows in the table are missing etc.

After a while of testing I found that removing the filter: alpha(opacity=100) (which was placed there by some fancy jquery-ui-script), resolves the issue.

So why does filter: alpha(opacity=100) break my printouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using this directive in the first place? If you want a block element to be visible, set it to `display: block`.

Anyway, as for the question on why your elements don't show up, you might want to read [this](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Comment: It wasn't me who added it. I actually fixed the issue by removing it. I don't really see how the article answers my question about why the filter-directive breaks my printouts?

Comment: Did not intend to sound confrontational, sorry. In IE, hasLayout is a property that causes the elements to render properly. Some elements, including <div>s, don't have hasLayout on by default, resulting in buggy behavior. In your case, it looks like the filter directive clashed with the fact that the <div> had no layout, resulting in the children not rendering properly. You can force an element to get layout by using the zoom: 1 hack, for example.

Comment: Ok..now I see your meaning. You are saying that the filter-attribute made it so that the elements "lost" layout in the world of IE7&8? Since I removed it everything works stellar.. :)